# Rails Alpha2 country to Real country name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using country gem https://github.com/hexorx/countries and trying to get the the country name from alpha2 country names. but it comes as [object object]. here is my code.

```
render :json => @countries.map { |c| [c.id, ::ISO3166::Country[c.country]] }
```

This returns aplha2 fine as expected, which is saved in country column:

```
render :json => @countries.map { |c| [c.id, c.country] }
```

Comment: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass, when you try english_short_name

Comment: That error message means `@countries` is `nil`.

Comment: What about `render :json => @countries.map { |c| [c.id, ::ISO3166::Country[c.country].name ] }` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass hash (`data`) instead of `Country` instance.

```
render :json => @countries.map { |c| [c.id, ::ISO3166::Country[c.country].data] }
```

If you want only country name, use `name`:

```
render :json => @countries.map { |c| [c.id, ::ISO3166::Country[c.country].name] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is accessing the translations, because for example sometimes the country name is not what you want e.g.: from "United States of America" to "United States"

```
country_code = "US"
country_label = ::ISO3166::Country[country_code].data["translations"]["en"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ISO3166::Country.find_country_by_alpha2(country_code)&.name
```